# Comparing bytes from to wav files

Tags: byte, wav

If I were to save an array of bytes from a recorded wave file, of someone saying their name for example. Then compare the array of bytes in a new wav file of the same person saying their name to the original one, would I be able to tell it was the same person saying their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are so many factors that simply comparing the file will not suffice. 

There's background noise and static, sample rate could be off from the first one, they could have their mouth closer to the microphone then last time..and that's without starting the technical stuff like your definition of 'compare', plus how many bytes you would have to 'compare' would be ridiculous - each byte is so small in relation to the whole thing they basically mean nothing individually.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will not go in this direction. I wonder how to accomplish something like this?